# ARM templates : Add a securityrule in a network security group with an Array of Ips

Tags: json, azure, azure-rm-template, network-security-groups

is there a way to add an array of sourceaddressprefixes for the same security rule , i already have the variable "sourceaddresspprefix" with single Ip

Comment: you want to specify a list of ips to populate the sourceaddressprefixes property ?

Comment: yes exactly i already have something like this , but i have many ips that goes under the same name and i want to regroup them in an array {
                    "name": "APP-05",
                    "source": "string",
                    "destination": "string",
                    "action": "Allow",
                    "port": ""
                    
                }

Comment: you could pass it as a comma separated list parameter => `ips:ip1,ip2` and then set the sourceaddressprefixes: `"[split(parameters('ips'), ',')]"`.